# How do I resolve the following issue on hyperledger composer cli command for identity issue?

Tags: composer-php, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXAb6.png) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSAYD.png)

```
From the following link
```

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.identity.issue.html

```
composer identity issue -c admin@mron-business-network -fsupplier -u suppid -a "resource:org.mron.Supplier#S001" -x false
Issue identity and create Network Card for: suppid

✖ Issuing identity. This may take a few seconds...
Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
Command failed
```

Answer (score 0):

same message posted on Rocketchat earlier. It would appear that the admin id in your card is not the one currently known to the CA server. After import using (for example) `composer card import -f <filename>`, you need to connect to the business network (or use `composer network ping -c admin@mron-business-network` to connect) - for the credentials (key/certificate) to be downloaded to the wallet from the CA server. You can then verify this with a `composer card list  --name admin@mron-business-network` and see the 'Credentials set' message for the card in question.

Comment: SIR My admin card credentials are set but unable run the identity issue command.✖ Issuing identity. This may take a few seconds...
Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
Command failed